# Union of long and char[], byte order

Tags: c, endianness, unions

If I do the following in code for an 8-bit processor:

```
typedef union
{
unsigned long longn ;
unsigned char chars[4];
} longbytes;
```

Is `longbytes.chars[0]` always going to be the lowest byte of `longbytes.longn`, or does it depend on endianness/compiler/platform/target/luck etc.?  I've viewed the disassembly of my complied code and that's how it is in my specific case, but I'm curious if this code is portable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several reasons why this is not portable:

- It depends on the endianess your platform (or compiler) enforces which byte is written first, so you can't count on `chars[0]` addressing the lowest byte
- `unsigned long` is not guaranteed to be exactly as long as `4` chars, so depending on the platform you might not even get the complete `long` (or sizeof(`long`) might be smaller then `4` and you read further, but that's unlikely for 8Bit processors at least.
- Reading a different union member then you wrote to is generally not portable, it is implementation defined behaviour. The reason for this is basically the combination of the two other issues.

So all in all that code is not portable at all.

Comment: In n1570, 6.5.2.3, footnote 95 reads "If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’). This might be a trap representation." So it's semi-defined nowadays.

Comment: I thought that the standard made a specific exception for type punning  for `unsigned char` arrays.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ok so it is actually implementation defined. Will fix my answer

Comment: Now. It was undefined before C11, iirc, so you were like five weeks behind. Considering how fast C99 was adopted, you should have left it undefined for at least another 5 years ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ah ok. Well even if it was nominally UB I would assume that in reality it was almost certainly implementation defined (would be a weird union implementation otherwise), so I think I will let it stand as implementation defined

Comment: Language lawyer territory. I'm not an expert in that matter, but I think technically, implementation defined means the standard said the implementation shall make a documented choice. Stuff like union type-punning where the standard used to not say anything about (except for common initial segments) but the implementations documented their choice by their own decision would still be UB. So if in three years a LL comes across your answer and cries foul, don't say I didn't warn you ;) Seriously, I agree, ID is the best fit, even if it may not be technically correct.

Answer (score 5):

In general, if you ever need to care about endianness you're doing something wrong, and need to work around your problem (e.g. with shifts and masks, or serialisation/de-serialisation).

For example, rather than having a union maybe you should do something like:

```
uint32_t pack(uint8_t byte0, uint8_t byte1, uint8_t byte2, uint8_t byte3) {
    long result;

    result = byte0;
    result |= byte1 << 8;
    result |= byte2 << 16;
    result |= byte3 << 24;
    return result;
}

uint8_t unpack(int byteNumber, uint32_t value) {
    return (value >> (byteNumber * 8));
}
```

Comment: The reason I was trying to access the bytes directly is because when I do it this way, the resulting code literally shifts the four bytes of the long and ORs in the data four times in a row, which is prohibitively slow for my application.  It does better with ints (it puts the data bytes in the appropriate register but still does an unnecessary OR), but it completely fails with longs.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the platform stores `long`s internally. Writing to one element of a union and then reading from another is not portable.

Answer (score 1):

The `union` data structure is portable as long as you do not cause undefined behavior by writing into one part of it and reading from the other. Specifically, writing to `unsigned long` and reading from `unsigned char[4]` or vice versa is undefined behavior.